# Animate more than one more div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I've tried the `.join()` function jQuery has to animate more than one object at the same time.

It failed my expectations. Here is my code.  Please tell me why exactly this wouldn't work?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 animateRight();
   var fourLevelMove = ["#CsecondObj", "#CnineObj"];
   var fourLevelMoveone = fourLevelMove.join();


function animateRight() {
$(fourLevelMoveone).animate({
    'marginLeft' : "+=220px" //moves left
 }, 900, 'swing', animateLeft);
}

function animateLeft() {
$(fourLevelMoveone).animate({
    'marginLeft' : "-=220px" //moves right
  }, 900, 'swing', animateRight);
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Will you try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //animateRight();//fourLevelMoveone IS NOT DEFINED YET
    var fourLevelMove = ["#CsecondObj", "#CnineObj"];
    var fourLevelMoveone = fourLevelMove.join(",");
    animateRight();

    function animateRight() {
        $(fourLevelMoveone).stop().animate({
            'marginLeft' : "+=20px" //moves left
         }, 900, 'swing', animateLeft);
    }

    function animateLeft() {
        $(fourLevelMoveone).stop().animate({
            'marginLeft' : "-=20px" //moves right
          }, 900, 'swing', animateRight);
     }
});
```

Here is <kbd>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3y0wxLgy/1/)</kbd> for it.

Update: Adding **`stop`** and changing margin keeps it in bounds.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/418v2wa5/2/, It goes off track now go to the bottom and the second object.

Comment: @NicholasAyoub what do you expect it to be?